# SQL query to retrieve only one occurrence for each id

Tags: sql, field

This is my (simplified) table:

```
id     eventName       seriesKey    eventStart
1      Event1          5000         2012-01-01 14:00:00
2      Event2          5001         2012-01-01 14:30:00
3      Event3          5000         2012-01-01 14:50:00
4      Event4          5002         2012-01-01 14:55:00
5      Event5          5001         2012-01-01 15:00:00
6      Event6          5002         2012-01-01 15:30:00
7      Event7          5002         2012-01-01 16:00:00
```

I have to build a query that orders the table by `eventStart (ASC)` but for each `seriesKey`, I need only one occurrence.

Thank you very much

Comment: Which EventStart should be the one returned? The first/last/don'tcare one?

Comment: Please include in your question what you would like your output to look like. Also, if you can supply the name of your table, that would help us providing an answer that's tailored for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also need the other columns associated with the key, you have two options:

```
select *
from (
  select id, 
         eventName, 
         seriesKey,
         eventStart,
         row_number() over (partition by seriesKey order by eventStart) as rn
  from the_event_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by eventStart
```

or for older DBMS that do not support windowing functions:

```
  select t1.id, 
         t1.eventName, 
         t1.seriesKey,
         t1.eventStart
  from the_event_table t1
  where t1.eventStart = (select min(t2.eventStart)
                         from the_event_table t2
                         where t2.seriesKey = t1.seriesKey)
  order by eventStart
```

Answer (score 4):

Try aggregating with GROUP BY and using aggregate functions like MIN().

```
SELECT seriesKey,
       MIN(eventStart) eventStart
FROM   events
GROUP  BY seriesKey;
```

This results in:

```
5000    2012-01-01 14:00:00.000
5001    2012-01-01 14:30:00.000
5002    2012-01-01 14:30:00.000
```

If your're interested in all columns from events table, not just the above two columns I choose, there's a freaky implementation in some databases (e.g. SQL Server) which may help you:

```
SELECT *
FROM   events e1
WHERE  e1.ID IN
(
       SELECT   TOP 1 e2.ID
       FROM     events e2
       WHERE    e2.seriesKey = e1.seriesKey
       ORDER BY e2.eventStart
);
```

Resulting in:

```
1   Event1  5000    2012-01-01 14:00:00.000
2   Event2  5001    2012-01-01 14:30:00.000
6   Event2  5002    2012-01-01 14:30:00.000
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work :( It only retrieves one row with the min eventStart value

Comment: @Alessandro are you sure it just retrieves one row? I tried it several times and it returns 3 rows. I've added the output I get to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can get earlier date for each seriesKey:

```
select * from 
(
select seriesKey, min(eventStart) as mindate
group by seriesKey
)
order by mindate
```